# SSL : Certifcate Verify failed using Python Requests library

Tags: security, openssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I am using owasp zap for security testing and i have made the following changes to the requests

```
requests.put(url=request_url, json=payload, headers=headers, proxies=PROXY, verify=CERT_PATH)
```

where the CERT_PATH points to the directory of ZAP dynamic SSL Certificate. But I am getting Exception: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed. I tried reading the answers in stackoverflow but nothing useful. I dont have much background in security I am trying to read stuff but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you please share the `request_url` variable.